# In a data frame, how to delete some rows by using an criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my data:

```
ID      nb     ecart    
ID1     3       NA  
ID1     3       0    
ID1     3       1.5 
ID2     2       NA  
ID2     2       648 
ID3     4       NA 
ID3     4       0  
ID3     4       0 
ID3     4       7
ID4     2       NA
ID4     2       37
```

And I whant to delete the rows which `ecart=0`, and also delete all the rows of the relatived ID.

Here is the expected result:

```
ID      nb     ecart       
ID2     2       NA  
ID2     2       648 
ID4     2       NA
ID4     2       37
```

Hope to get your answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!any(ecart==0 & !is.na(ecart)))
#   ID nb ecart
#1 ID2  2    NA
#2 ID2  2   648
#3 ID4  2    NA
#4 ID4  2    37
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(!any(ecart==0 & !is.na(ecart))) .SD, ID]
#    ID nb ecart
#1: ID2  2    NA
#2: ID2  2   648
#3: ID4  2    NA
#4: ID4  2    37
```

Or as @David Arenburg suggested, we can use `all` instead of `any` by altering the condition slightly

```
setDT(df1)[, if(all(na.omit(ecart) != 0L)) .SD, by = ID]
#    ID nb ecart
#1: ID2  2    NA
#2: ID2  2   648
#3: ID4  2    NA
#4: ID4  2    37
```

Or using `base R`

```
subset(df1, !ID %in% unique(ID[ecart==0 & !is.na(ecart)]))
#    ID nb ecart
#4  ID2  2    NA
#5  ID2  2   648
#10 ID4  2    NA
#11 ID4  2    37
```

Comment: If I have two IDs, so I should do as this `df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID1,ID2) %>% 
  filter(!any(ecart==0 & !is.na(ecart)))`? (For each ID1, it have several ID2)

Comment: @velvetrock I guess that would work. If there is any trouble, please let me know